# Can anyone tell me why my reference isn't getting returned?

Tags: perl

I'm writing a parser for the Netscreen firewall configuration files to create some scripts that do the same things as the scripts I have using PIX::Walker. I ran into a problem where the reference I create in the parseconfig sub looks fine in Dump 1, but is empty in Dump 2.  I'm working on a cleaner approach right now, but I was wondering if anyone could tell me why Dump 2 shows that reference to be empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
use Data::Dumper;

my $usage = "Usage: isg-ppsrpt.pl -d config directory
-d is required
use portproto-rpt.pl -h to get this help\n\n";

my @firewalls = ("foo","bar","baz");

my %opts;
my %configs;

getopts('hd:', \%opts);

if ($opts{h}) { die $usage };

# Parser definition
my %parse;

$parse{service} = sub {
 my $ref = shift;
 my @elements = split(/\s+/, shift);
 @elements[2]  =~ /\"(\S+)\"/;
 my $name = $1;
 my $out;
 if ($elements[4] =~ /tcp|udp/) {
  $out->{proto} = $elements[4];
  $out->{port} = $elements[-1];
 }
 if ($out) {push @{$ref->{service}{$name}}, $out};
};


foreach (@firewalls) {
 my $fw = sprintf "%s\\%s.config",$opts{d},$_;
 if (-e $fw) {
  $configs{$_} = parseconfig($fw);
 } else {
  die "Cannot find config file for $_ in \n";
 }
}

sub parseconfig {
  my $configref;
  my $configfile = shift;
  open (CONFIG,"$configfile");
  foreach my $line (<CONFIG>) {
   chomp $line;
   my $type = (split(/\s+/,$line))[1];
   if ($parse{$type}) {
    $parse{$type}($configref,$line);
   }
   print Dumper(%$configref); # Dump 1
  }
  close(CONFIG);
  print Dumper(%$configref); # Dump 2
  return($configref);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through autovivification, you assign a hash reference to `$ref`. However, that reference is never assigned fo `$configref` in the caller.

Changing `$ref` does not change `$configref`, so `$configref` remains undefined. Changing `$_[0]` would change `$configref` since `$_[0]` is aliased to `$configref`.

You must find a way of placing the same reference in `$ref` and `$configref`.

Solution 1:

```
$parse{service} = sub {
    my $ref = $_[0] ||= {};
    ...
};

my $configref;
...
$parse{$type}($configref, $line);
```

Solution 2:

```
$parse{service} = sub {
    my $ref = $_[0];
    ...
};

my %config;
...
$parse{$type}(\%config, $line);
```

Solution 3:

```
$parse{service} = sub {
    my %config;
    ...
    return %config;
};

my %config;
...
%config = ( %config, $parse{$type}($line) );
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. I actually used: `$parse{service} = sub{ my $ref = shift ... return{$ref}` and `$configref = $parse{type}($configref, $line)` and that worked without declaring a global variable.

Comment: @ElectricWeasel: or you could just have changed parseconfig to do `my $configref = {};` instead of `my $configref;`

Comment: @ElectricWeasel, @ysth: That's solution 2. I just spelled it differently.

Answer (score 2):

```
sub parseconfig {
    my $configref;
    ....
    if ($parse{$type}) {
        $parse{$type}($configref,$line);
```

I don't know that this explains your problem, but it looks like you are relying on the called function to populate $configref.  This will only work if it directly uses `$_[0]` (an alias to the passed parameter `$configref`);  if it assigns it to a lexical and uses that, `$configref` itself will be left undefined.  Initializing `$configref` to `{}` in parseconfig fixes this.

Comment: Using a globally scoped string instead of one scoped to parseconfig does solve the problem. I thought I had tried that. The anonymous sub declared in $parse{service} does shift off $_[0] to populate the hash reference. I confirmed this with Dump 1, but when I tried looking at the reference right before parseconfig returns the reference it was empty. Since $configref was scoped at the parseconfig level, that doesn't make sense to me. I'm going to leave this unanswered for a little longer to see if anyone can explain to me why.

Comment: @ElectricWeasel: shifting off `$_[0]` is not the same as directly using it;  a copy of it into another variable won't be aliased.  If you can include sample config files that trigger the problem, it would be easier to see exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Now I see it, I need to pass the reference back. I gave the answer to ikegami because I understood his explanation better. But thanks for the help.